# How to convert geometry_msgs/Pose to geometry_msgs/PoseStamped

Tags: ros, pose, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to convert a message from geometry_msgs/Pose to geometry_msgs/PoseStamped. Is there ay functionality in ROS to do the same ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225741/how-to-convert-geometry_msgs/pose-to-geometry_msgs/posestamped/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` contains two fields. `header` and `pose`.

You can create an empty PoseStamped and set `pose` to your `geometry_msgs/Pose`.
If you want you can also set some fields in the header.

No black magic.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1